# Manipulate text from form - JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am working on a project and last night I had a thought that would make a lot of what I am wanting to do a heck of a lot easier, the only problem is I am not sure on the best way to tackle it. Let me explain....

I have a form on a website where a user enters a VIP ID that is in a pre-determined format and follows a logical naming convention.

Example: **app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb**

I want to pull out the following information from the entered text.

**prod.platform.org.**

Then I want to reverse it logically 
**.org.platform.prod**

And then I want to replace the “.” For “/”
**/org/platform/prod**

And finally I want to add a postfix of  “/open*”
**/org/platform/prod/open***

So in short,

**INPUT** = app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb

**OUTPUT** = /org/platform/prod/open*

I am using javascript/jquery for everything else but I am pretty new to all of this so I tend not to know the best route to tackle a problem. If I need to provide some more detail I can do. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will it always be `prod.platform.org` or can it change? Will it always follow from `app.`?

Comment: No, but the format always follows the same naming convention, so it could be proda.platforms.organization.....

Comment: The answer by @searlea should work.

Comment: @user3236169, [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simple like this

```
var input = "app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb" ;
var output =
  "/" +
  input 
    .split(".")
    .slice(1, 4)
    .reverse()
    .join("/") +
  "/open";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var output =
  "/" +
  "app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb"
    .split(".")
    .slice(1, 4)
    .reverse()
    .join("/") +
  "/open";
```

Comment: Thanks Searlea. Say the form input id is 'one' can I replace

 "app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb"

for

'#one' ?

Comment: `var one = "app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb" ;
var output =
  "/" +
  one
    .split(".")
    .slice(1, 4)
    .reverse()
    .join("/") +
  "/open";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code :

```
var input = "app.prod.platform.org.dc1.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb";
            var tempArr = input.split(".");
            var newArr = new Array();
            for(var i=1;i<tempArr.length;i++){
                if(tempArr[i]=="org" || tempArr[i]=="net"){
                    newArr.push(tempArr[i]);
                    break;
                }
                newArr.push(tempArr[i]);
            }
            newArr.reverse();
            var output="/"+newArr.join("/")+"/open*";
```